# How to select path svg with special classe with css

Tags: css, svg

How to select the second path of a svg with its class name to be fill in yellow ?
If I try with the id of the svg it works but not if I select the special class name.
I would like to fill sometimes in green, yellow or red, and the special class is different on page loaded but on value of a php variable...

I tried :

```
#icon-conducteur path:nth-of-type(2) {fill: #fef200 !important} // Works
svg.cond_niv_1 #icon-conducteur path:nth-of-type(2) {fill: #fef200 !important} // failed
```

in :

```
<svg class="svg-70 cond_niv_1">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-conducteur"> path...
    </use></svg>
```

```css
svg.svg-70 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
/* Failed :*/
 svg.cond_niv_1 #icon-conducteur path:nth-of-type(2) {
  fill: #fef200 !important;
 }

/* Works !!! but without svg class name 
#icon-conducteur path:nth-of-type(2) {
  fill: #fef200 !important;
}
*/
```

```html
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<svg class="cond_niv_1" width="0" height="0">
<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0, 0, 100, 100" id="icon-conducteur">
    <path d="M48.957 17.832c-.813.222-1.367.905-4.784 5.948-1.958 2.9-4.692 6.945-6.077 8.977a2405.88 2405.88 0 0 0-4.821 7.112c-1.256 1.884-4.138 6.113-6.373 9.42a39442.555 39442.555 0 0 0-15.719 23.237C8.69 76.238 7.12 78.732 7.046 79.12c-.204 1.034.406 2.161 1.403 2.66l.813.388H90.72l.813-.425c.665-.333.905-.573 1.201-1.293.332-.831.332-.942.074-1.663-.148-.424-3.177-4.968-6.724-10.103-3.528-5.135-7.407-10.751-8.589-12.468a2760.582 2760.582 0 0 1-5.412-7.851c-1.792-2.586-4.045-5.874-5.024-7.296-.979-1.422-4.729-6.871-8.331-12.099-3.602-5.227-6.797-9.826-7.093-10.196-.351-.425-.831-.757-1.256-.886-.72-.185-.831-.203-1.422-.056z"></path>
    <path d="M53.298 30.3c-1.903-2.789-3.51-5.098-3.565-5.135-.111-.11-.665.665-3.122 4.286-1.071 1.625-3.731 5.56-5.911 8.755-6.779 10.03-11.71 17.308-14.5 21.427-9.919 14.666-11.507 17.03-11.507 17.178 0 .129 12.579.185 35.298.185 31.734 0 35.299-.037 35.188-.277-.055-.167-.72-1.182-1.459-2.272-.757-1.09-2.217-3.233-3.27-4.747-3.084-4.47-5.763-8.368-7.037-10.197-.647-.942-2.549-3.712-4.23-6.15-1.681-2.439-4.525-6.576-6.336-9.199-1.791-2.605-3.897-5.671-4.673-6.779-.757-1.127-2.955-4.304-4.876-7.075z"
      fill="#FFF"></path>
    <path d="M34.604 65.558c3.314-.05 5.139 3.52 3.122 6.173-1.736 2.106-5.135 1.718-6.243-.738-.942-2.051.074-4.507 2.143-5.228.54-.163.217-.081.978-.207zm.174 1.666c-.956.08-1.64.654-1.983 1.534-.277.849-.074 1.477.665 2.142 1.348 1.182 3.583.259 3.583-1.477 0-.665-.517-1.571-1.09-1.903-.406-.248-.718-.263-1.175-.296zm27.483-.031c.79.163.46.046 1.011.29 1.09.573 1.404 1.995.684 3.066-1.183 1.755-3.824.887-3.824-1.237 0-.721.092-.942.628-1.478.441-.385.889-.654 1.501-.641zm.127-1.623c-.513.022-.964.013-1.443.214-1.552.609-2.475 1.939-2.475 3.583 0 3.214 3.786 4.913 6.206 2.771.942-.813 1.238-1.515 1.238-2.826-.019-1.293-.314-1.995-1.238-2.808-.669-.546-1.414-.864-2.288-.934zm-9.829-9.816l1.902.018c1.035 0 2.162.093 2.494.222.351.129 1.57 1.053 2.752 2.069l2.124 1.847-1.921.111c-1.034.074-3.121.184-4.617.258l-2.734.13v-4.655zm-1.663 0v2.29c0 2.217-.018 2.291-.406 2.401-.776.204-10.602.351-10.399.167.111-.111 1.422-1.035 2.918-2.088 3.417-2.364 4.322-2.752 6.373-2.77h1.514zm1.783-1.647l-.859.003c-3.491 0-4.378.055-5.523.351-.739.203-1.773.628-2.309.942-1.127.702-6.834 4.655-7.555 5.264-.277.24-.886.48-1.385.536-2.567.369-5.523 1.33-7.037 2.309-.979.628-1.053.757-1.441 1.958-.24.72-.425 1.718-.425 2.253 0 .85.055.979.609 1.404.647.499 1.977 1.034 2.531 1.034.259 0 .333-.221.406-1.256.333-4.525 5.412-6.52 8.7-3.38 1.016.942 1.46 1.921 1.57 3.38l.093 1.256h16.938v-.812c0-1.275.536-2.642 1.422-3.621 2.438-2.715 6.816-2.105 8.442 1.145.258.536.48 1.275.48 1.644 0 .388.074.739.166.795.259.166 2.697-1.829 3.14-2.549.314-.518.388-.905.388-2.346 0-3.14-.554-4.082-2.549-4.304-1.071-.129-1.385-.277-4.248-2.161-3.658-2.42-5.634-3.436-7.149-3.676a10.741 10.741 0 0 0-1.029-.091 71.718 71.718 0 0 0-3.376-.078z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-70 cond_niv_1">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-conducteur"></use>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a `svg.cond_niv_1` You have a `svg#cond_niv_1`. Your svg element has an id not a class

Comment: side note: You have a 100x100 viewbox, but precision is x.nnn So if your icon is 100x100 PIXELS you stuff a 1000 pixels into 1 pixel . Simplify your SVG with SVGOMG https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Comment: @enxaneta : Sorry, this is a recopy error. Whether with a class or an id it doesn't work...

Comment: @Danny : great tool ! thanks.

Comment: Also [be careful not to cross the shadow boundary with your CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseStyleInheritance).

Comment: Do I understand that this is not possible in pure css ?
too bad, i got around the problem in javascript
Thanks for your help

Comment: Of course it is possible with CSS, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is Specificity,
when you stick a `fill="#FFF"` (original Triangle fill) on an SVG element, it means you can't change it with CSS
because inline styles always get higher Specificity, that is why `!important` works... it breaks Specificity.

So you have to do it the other way around:

- Protect the "car" from being filled. With `<path fill="black"`
- then fill the triangle (and simplifying the triangle from 2 paths to a Polygon it is **much** easier)
- Thus `fill:red` sets the fill for **all** SVG elements *inside* the Symbol.. but car is 'protected', And the triangle line is drawn with `stroke="black"`

[image]

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icon" viewBox="0, 0, 100, 100">

    <polygon points="50 20 90 90 10 90" 
             stroke="black" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>

    <path id="car" fill="black" 
          d="M35 70c3 0 5 3 3 6-2 2-5 1-7-1 0-2 1-5 3-5h1zm0 1l-2 2v2c2 1 4 0 4-2l-1-1-1-1zm27 0h1c1 1 2 2 1 4-1 1-4 0-4-2l1-1 1-1zm0-1h-1c-2 0-3 2-3 3 0 4 4 5 7 3l1-3-1-2-3-1zm-9-10h4l3 2 2 2h-9v-4zm-2 0v2l-1 2-10 1 3-2c3-3 4-3 6-3h2zm2-2h-7l-2 1a181 181 0 00-9 6l-7 3-1 1-1 3 1 1 2 1 1-1c0-5 5-7 8-3 1 0 2 1 2 3v1h17v-1l1-3a5 5 0 019 3h1l3-2v-3c0-3-1-4-3-4l-4-2-7-4a11 11 0 00-1 0 72 72 0 00-3 0z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
<style>
  .svg-70 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    fill: green; /* default fill */
  }
  .alert {
    fill: red;
  }
  .warning {
    fill: orange;
  }

</style>
<svg class="svg-70 alert">   <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>    </svg>
<svg class="svg-70 warning"> <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>    </svg>
<svg class="svg-70">         <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>    </svg>
```

## The 2020 way - [Custom Elements](https://www.dannymoerkerke.com/blog/web-components-will-replace-your-frontend-framework)

If you do not have to support IE anymore (and why would you?)

All modern browser support creating your own HTML:

#### `<alert-icon fill="red" width="70"></alert-icon>`

- easier to use semantic HTML
- No more `<symbol>` because the Custom Element generates the SVG
- No more CSS because the Custom Element sets **inline** Style `fill=...`
- Like attributes on standard DOM Elements always configurable with:
  `[element].setAttribute("fill","blue")`
  `[element].setAttribute("width","200")`

[image]

```html
<alert-icon fill="red" width="100"></alert-icon>
<alert-icon fill="orange" width="75"></alert-icon>
<alert-icon fill="yellow" width="50"></alert-icon>

<script>
  customElements.define('alert-icon', class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["fill", "width"]; // update whenever these attributes change
    }
    attributeChangedCallback() {
      let width = this.getAttribute("width");
      let fill = this.getAttribute("fill");
      this.innerHTML = `<svg width="${width}" height="${width}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">  
<polygon fill="${fill}" points="50 20 90 90 10 90" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>  
<path d="M35 70c3 0 5 3 3 6-2 2-5 1-7-1 0-2 1-5 3-5h1zm0 1l-2 2v2c2 1 4 0 4-2l-1-1-1-1zm27 0h1c1 1 2 2 1 4-1 1-4 0-4-2l1-1 1-1zm0-1h-1c-2 0-3 2-3 3 0 4 4 5 7 3l1-3-1-2-3-1zm-9-10h4l3 2 2 2h-9v-4zm-2 0v2l-1 2-10 1 3-2c3-3 4-3 6-3h2zm2-2h-7l-2 1a181 181 0 00-9 6l-7 3-1 1-1 3 1 1 2 1 1-1c0-5 5-7 8-3 1 0 2 1 2 3v1h17v-1l1-3a5 5 0 019 3h1l3-2v-3c0-3-1-4-3-4l-4-2-7-4a11 11 0 00-1 0 72 72 0 00-3 0z"/>  
</svg>`
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: glad to be of help, if the answer is correct you can mark it as answered so StackOverflow is kept organized.

Answer (score -1):

Had to use Javascrip to do it...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 if ($('.cond_niv_1').length > 0) {
  $('#icon-conducteur path:nth-of-type(2)').css('fill','#fef200');
 } else  if ($('.cond_niv_2').length > 0) {
  $('#icon-conducteur path:nth-of-type(2)').css('fill','#ffae16');
 } else  if ($('.cond_niv_3').length > 0) {
  $('#icon-conducteur path:nth-of-type(2)').css('fill','#ed1b24');
 }
});
```

```css
svg.svg-70 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<svg class="cond_niv_1" width="0" height="0">
<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0, 0, 100, 100" id="icon-conducteur">
    <path d="M48.957 17.832c-.813.222-1.367.905-4.784 5.948-1.958 2.9-4.692 6.945-6.077 8.977a2405.88 2405.88 0 0 0-4.821 7.112c-1.256 1.884-4.138 6.113-6.373 9.42a39442.555 39442.555 0 0 0-15.719 23.237C8.69 76.238 7.12 78.732 7.046 79.12c-.204 1.034.406 2.161 1.403 2.66l.813.388H90.72l.813-.425c.665-.333.905-.573 1.201-1.293.332-.831.332-.942.074-1.663-.148-.424-3.177-4.968-6.724-10.103-3.528-5.135-7.407-10.751-8.589-12.468a2760.582 2760.582 0 0 1-5.412-7.851c-1.792-2.586-4.045-5.874-5.024-7.296-.979-1.422-4.729-6.871-8.331-12.099-3.602-5.227-6.797-9.826-7.093-10.196-.351-.425-.831-.757-1.256-.886-.72-.185-.831-.203-1.422-.056z"></path>
    <path d="M53.298 30.3c-1.903-2.789-3.51-5.098-3.565-5.135-.111-.11-.665.665-3.122 4.286-1.071 1.625-3.731 5.56-5.911 8.755-6.779 10.03-11.71 17.308-14.5 21.427-9.919 14.666-11.507 17.03-11.507 17.178 0 .129 12.579.185 35.298.185 31.734 0 35.299-.037 35.188-.277-.055-.167-.72-1.182-1.459-2.272-.757-1.09-2.217-3.233-3.27-4.747-3.084-4.47-5.763-8.368-7.037-10.197-.647-.942-2.549-3.712-4.23-6.15-1.681-2.439-4.525-6.576-6.336-9.199-1.791-2.605-3.897-5.671-4.673-6.779-.757-1.127-2.955-4.304-4.876-7.075z"
      fill="#FFF"></path>
    <path d="M34.604 65.558c3.314-.05 5.139 3.52 3.122 6.173-1.736 2.106-5.135 1.718-6.243-.738-.942-2.051.074-4.507 2.143-5.228.54-.163.217-.081.978-.207zm.174 1.666c-.956.08-1.64.654-1.983 1.534-.277.849-.074 1.477.665 2.142 1.348 1.182 3.583.259 3.583-1.477 0-.665-.517-1.571-1.09-1.903-.406-.248-.718-.263-1.175-.296zm27.483-.031c.79.163.46.046 1.011.29 1.09.573 1.404 1.995.684 3.066-1.183 1.755-3.824.887-3.824-1.237 0-.721.092-.942.628-1.478.441-.385.889-.654 1.501-.641zm.127-1.623c-.513.022-.964.013-1.443.214-1.552.609-2.475 1.939-2.475 3.583 0 3.214 3.786 4.913 6.206 2.771.942-.813 1.238-1.515 1.238-2.826-.019-1.293-.314-1.995-1.238-2.808-.669-.546-1.414-.864-2.288-.934zm-9.829-9.816l1.902.018c1.035 0 2.162.093 2.494.222.351.129 1.57 1.053 2.752 2.069l2.124 1.847-1.921.111c-1.034.074-3.121.184-4.617.258l-2.734.13v-4.655zm-1.663 0v2.29c0 2.217-.018 2.291-.406 2.401-.776.204-10.602.351-10.399.167.111-.111 1.422-1.035 2.918-2.088 3.417-2.364 4.322-2.752 6.373-2.77h1.514zm1.783-1.647l-.859.003c-3.491 0-4.378.055-5.523.351-.739.203-1.773.628-2.309.942-1.127.702-6.834 4.655-7.555 5.264-.277.24-.886.48-1.385.536-2.567.369-5.523 1.33-7.037 2.309-.979.628-1.053.757-1.441 1.958-.24.72-.425 1.718-.425 2.253 0 .85.055.979.609 1.404.647.499 1.977 1.034 2.531 1.034.259 0 .333-.221.406-1.256.333-4.525 5.412-6.52 8.7-3.38 1.016.942 1.46 1.921 1.57 3.38l.093 1.256h16.938v-.812c0-1.275.536-2.642 1.422-3.621 2.438-2.715 6.816-2.105 8.442 1.145.258.536.48 1.275.48 1.644 0 .388.074.739.166.795.259.166 2.697-1.829 3.14-2.549.314-.518.388-.905.388-2.346 0-3.14-.554-4.082-2.549-4.304-1.071-.129-1.385-.277-4.248-2.161-3.658-2.42-5.634-3.436-7.149-3.676a10.741 10.741 0 0 0-1.029-.091 71.718 71.718 0 0 0-3.376-.078z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-70 cond_niv_1">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-conducteur"></use>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```